# ASMX Web Service only displays request when clicking invoke from browser

Tags: asp.net, iis, asmx

I have the web service (developed in .net 4.0) and published in local IIS 7.0 
When I go to the browser, I can see the asmx invoke operation. When passing the values and click "invoke" I get only the XML for request, but with values passed in 0, like this:

```
<H_Receptores xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://mywebsite.com/app">
<UserID>0</UserID>
<ReceptorID>0</ReceptorID>
</H_Receptores>
```

This should be values of 1 and 2 (what I entered in the web service form).

What should I do, or what I'm doing worng?

By the way, in Visual Studio 2010, if I right click and select view on browser, it opens a local development temporary IIS on port :41089 and there the operation works superb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why did you create an ASMX service if you were using .NET 4.0. ASMX is a legacy technology, supported only for backwards compatability. All new SOAP web service development should use WCF.

Second, don't worry about how it works in the browser! You're not going to invoke the application from the "help page", are you? In order to test your service, create some form of client to consume the service. An example would be to create a small console application, use "Add Service Reference" to reference the service, then have the consle application call the service.

I find it more convenient to use Unit Test projects for this purpose, BTW, since I can create a set of tests and execute them all at once.

Comment: In .NET 4.0+ not even WCF, but Web API should be used I think.

Comment: @Trekstuff: web API is only for REST services.

Comment: Thanks to all who participated. I changed to WCF Service and it was much better. Also, I achieve my ultimate goal of this POC, consumed the WCF service from Android.